# Query not using indexes using using Table function

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, oracle12c

I have following query:

```
select i.pkey as instrument_pkey,
       p.asof,
       p.price,
       p.lastprice as lastprice,
       p.settlementprice as settlement_price,
       p.snaptime,
       p.owner as source_id,
       i.type as instrument_type
from quotes_mxsequities p,
     instruments i,
     (select instrument, maxbackdays
      from TABLE(cast (:H_ARRAY as R_TAB))) lbd
where p.asof between :ASOF - lbd.maxbackdays and :ASOF
  and p.instrument = lbd.instrument
  and p.owner = :SOURCE_ID
  and p.instrument = i.pkey
```

Since I have started using table function, query has started doing full table scan on table `quotes_mxsequities` which is large table.

Earlier when I used `IN` clause include of table function index was being used.

Any suggestion on how to enforce index usage?

EDIT:

I will try to get explain plan but just to add, `H_ARRAY` is expected to have around 10k entries. `quotes_mxsequities` is a large table millions of rows. Instruments is again a large table but has lesser rows than `quotes_mxsequities`.
Full table scan is happening for `quotes_mxsequities` while `instruments` is using index

Comment: Is `HARRAY` going to be quite a small subset of the data in `quotes_mxsequities` - how many rows ar ein the table, and how many do you expect to match? i.e. is an index actually going to be appropriate?

Comment: @Alex: HARRAY can have around 10k rows while quotes_mxsequities is a huge table with millions of rows. We exoect to match around 2 million rows.

Comment: If you're matching 2 million rows out of millions or even tens of millions, a full table scan might be more efficient anyway. Are you just seeing a different plan, or is the performance actually worse than it was with the `IN` - assuming the array and matching data were the same?

Comment: @Alex: So it performs very well if it uses index and finishes in 2-3 minutes while with full table scan it takes hours. With in clause it was taking around 4 minutes.

Comment: OK, does the cardinality hint help? I'm not sure it will with the array that big but worth trying. Or the dynamic sampling hint, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Quite difficult to answer with no explain plan and informations about table structure, number of rows, etc.

As a general, simplified approach, you could try to force the use on an index with the [`INDEX` hint](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements006.htm#SQLRF50405).

Your problem can even be due to a wrong order in table processing; you can try to make Oracle follow the right order ( I suppose `LBD` first) with the [`LEADING` hint](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements006.htm#SQLRF50705).

Another point could be the full access, while you probably need a NESTED LOOP; in this case you can try the [USE_NL hint](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements006.htm#SQLRF50709)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to be sure form the limited information provided, but it looks like this is an issue with the optimiser not being able to establish the cardinality of the table collection expression, since its contents aren't known at parse time. With a stored nested table the statistics would be available, but here there are none for it to use.

Without that information the optimiser defaults to guessing your table collection will have 8K entries, and uses that as the cardinality estimate; if that is a significant proportion of the number of rows in `quotes_mxsequities` then it will decide the index isn't going to be efficient, and will use a full table scan.

You can use the [undocumented `cardinality` hint](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2233040800346569775) to tell the optimiser roughly how many elements you actually expect in the collection; you presumably won't know exactly, but you might know you usually expect around 10. So you could add a hint:

```
select /*+ CARDINALITY(lbd, 10) */ i.pkey as instrument_pkey,
```

You may also find the dynamic sampling hint useful here, but without your real data to look at, the cardinality hint applies to the basic execution plan so it's easy to see its effect.

Incidentally, you don't need the subquery on the table expression, you can simplify slightly to:

```
from TABLE(cast (:H_ARRAY as R_TAB)) lbd,
     quotes_mxsequities p,
     instruments i
```

or even better use modern join syntax:

```
select /*+ CARDINALITY(lbd, 10) */ i.pkey as instrument_pkey,
       p.asof,
       p.price,
       p.lastprice as lastprice,
       p.settlementprice as settlement_price,
       p.snaptime,
       p.owner as source_id,
       i.type as instrument_type
from TABLE(cast (:H_ARRAY as R_TAB)) lbd
join quotes_mxsequities p
on p.asof between :ASOF - lbd.maxbackdays and :ASOF
  and p.instrument = lbd.instrument
join instruments i
on i.pkey = p.instrument
where p.owner = :SOURCE_ID;
```